# Learn the sum of two numbers in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a neural network to predict the sum of two numbers. But I don't understand what's wrong with my model. Model consists of 2 inputs, 2 hidden and 1 output layers. Every 1000 iteration I print test execution, but the result is getting smaller and smaller.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


input_size = 2
hidden_size = 3
out_size = 1


def generate_test_data():
    inp = 0.5*np.random.rand(10, 2)
    oup = np.zeros((10, 1))
    for idx, val in enumerate(inp):
        oup[idx] = np.array([val[0] + val[1]])
    return inp, oup


def create_network():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size])

    w01 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_size, hidden_size], stddev=0.1))
    y1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(tf.sigmoid(x), w01))

    w12 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_size, out_size], stddev=0.1))
    y2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(y1, w12))

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, out_size])
    return x, y_, y2


def train(x, y_, y2):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y2)
    )
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    # Train
    for i in range(100000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = generate_test_data()
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

        # Test
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            out_batch = sess.run(y2, {x: batch_xs})
            inx = 0
            print(batch_xs[inx][0], " + ", batch_xs[inx][1], " = ", out_batch[inx][0])



(x, y_, y2) = create_network()
train(x, y_, y2)
```

Output every 1000 iteration:

```
0.37301352864927173  + 0.28949461772342683  = 0.49111518
0.050899466843458474 + 0.006174158992116541 = 0.0025260744
0.3974852369427063   + 0.22402098418952499  = 0.00090828544
0.15735921047969498  + 0.39645077887600294  = 0.0005903727
0.23560825884336228  + 0.29010766384718145  = 0.0004317883
0.4250063393420791   + 0.24181166029062096  = 0.00031525563
                                            = smaller and smaller
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-entropy loss is used for *classification* problems, while your task is clearly a *regression*. The computed `cross_entropy` value doesn't make sense, hence the result.

Change your loss to:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.l2_loss(y_ - y2)
)
```

... and you'll see much more sensible results.

Comment: If you want to do it in a straightforward way: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error

Answer (score 0):

Maxim, thanks a lot. Now it's work.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


input_size = 2
hidden_size = 3
out_size = 1


def generate_test_data():
    inp = 0.5*np.random.rand(10, 2)
    oup = np.zeros((10, 1))
    for idx, val in enumerate(inp):
        oup[idx] = np.array([val[0] + val[1]])
    return inp, oup


def create_network():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size])

    w01 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_size, hidden_size], stddev=0.1))
    y1 = tf.matmul(x, w01)

    w12 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_size, out_size], stddev=0.1))
    y2 = tf.matmul(y1, w12)

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, out_size])
    return x, y_, y2


def train(x, y_, y2):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.l2_loss(y_ - y2)
    )
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    # Train
    for i in range(100000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = generate_test_data()
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

        # Test
        if i % 2000 == 0:
            out_batch = sess.run(y2, {x: batch_xs})
            inx = 0
            print(batch_xs[inx][0], " + ", batch_xs[inx][1], " = ", out_batch[inx][0], "|", batch_xs[inx][0] + batch_xs[inx][1])


(x, y_, y2) = create_network()
train(x, y_, y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider predicting each digit to be a classification problem where you predict a value in "0123456789 ", you can use cross-entropy as your loss. For reference, see the [Keras - Addition RNN Example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/addition_rnn.py).

But like Maxim said, it shouldn't be used for a regression problem.